# Открытие файла по двойному клику

Tags: objective-c, macos

Добрый день.

Я пишу приложение для Mac для просмотра фотографий и не могу реализовать открытие файлов по двойному клику.

Я знаю, что есть метод делегата приложения:

`- (BOOL)application:(NSApplication *)theApplication openFile:(NSString *)filename`

и что когда пользователь открывает файл двойным нажатием, он срабатывает раньше метода:

`- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification`

и позже метода:

`- (void)applicationWillFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification`

Но как их грамотно использовать, чтоб файл открывался, когда приложение полностью закрыто (выгружено из памяти)?

Помогите, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 1):

```
- (void)mouseUp:(NSEvent *)event
{
    NSInteger clickCount = [event clickCount];
    if (2 == clickCount) [self handleDoubleClickEvent:event];
}
```